# ColdFusion 8 + MSSQL 2005 and CLOB datatype on resultset

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance, coldfusion, clob

The environment I am working with is CF8 and SQL 2005 and the datatype CLOB is **disabled** on the CF administrator. My concern is, will there be a performance ramification by enabling the CLOB datatype in the CF Administrator.

The reason I want/need to enable it is, SQL is building the AJAX XML response. When the response is large, the result is either truncated or returned with multiple rows (depending on how the SQL developer created the stored proc). Enabling CLOB allows the entire result to be returned. The other option I have is to have SQL always return the XML result in multiple rows and have CF join the string for each result row.

Anyone with some experience with this idea or have any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I really think that returning Clob data is likely to be less expensive then concatenating multiple rows of data into an XML string and then parsing it (ick!). What you are trying to do is what CLOB is designed for. JDBC handles it pretty well. The performance hit is probably negligible. After all - you have to return the same amount of character data either way, whether in multiple rows or a single field. And to have to "break it up" on the SQL side and then "reassemble" it on the CF side seems like reinventing the wheel to be sure.

I would add that questions like this sometimes mystify me. A modest amount of testing would seem to be able to answer this question to your own satisfaction - no?

Comment: I tend to agree with you about the performance being likely better if the jdbc handles it. Yes you're correct in saying that the characters have to be returned anyway but the switch to make SQL return on result row/column vs multiple rows with one column is pretty simple. It's either using a temp table or a variable. Using a temp table by default with split the xml response vs a variable won't. One thing I gain from joining the data back together in CF is that the issue is isolated vs turning on CLOB for the entire site.

Comment: You're right in saying that testing would prove or disprove any issues but like you said before "seems like reinventing the wheel", I too think that someone has considered this before. Regardless I need to test but I am looking for something that I may have not considered or any "gotcha's" out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have the StoredProc return the data set, or multiple data sets, and just build the XML the way you need it via CF.

I've never needed to use CLOB.   I almost always stick to the varchar datatype, and it seems to do the job just fine.

There are also options where you could call the Stored Proc, which triggers MSSQL to generate an actual xml file (not just a string) and simply return you the file name.   Then you can use **CFFILE action="read"** to grab the xml string and parse it accrodingly.  Assuming your web server and db have a common file storage area.

Comment: Jason, see my comment below. JDBC will handle this just fine. If there are adequate resources to handle 10k of character data in multiple rows, then there are adequate resources to send in a single field as well. That's my take (no offense :)  CMS systems often rely on large text via JDBC. It's what it is designed for.

Comment: @TheJason: FYI, to avoid confusion I modified the post to say "varchar" rather than "text" (which is a clob type in sql server;). If that is not what you meant, just roll it back.

Comment: @Mark A Kruger: Agreed, and no offense taken.  Like I said, I've never had a need for CLOB, so what the hell do I know :)   But thanks for sparking my interest in CLOB'ing.